# Having trailing space issue while storing GridView data in SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

As per my requirement there is need of Uploding Excel data in SQL Server 2008

But there is one issue.....

WHEN I am uploading an Excel sheet and showing it's content in Gridview and then I am storing it in SQL Server 2008 database;

In the GridView, Excel data is showing perfectly, but when I am storing it into the database, then at the end of string `&#160;` is inserted...

Stored data in table is `PETER&#160;` while it should be `PETER`

I have tried using the `.Trim()` method also but nothing is worked

```
foreach (GridViewRow g1 in grvExcelData.Rows)
{
   try
   {
       name = grvExcelData.Rows[g1.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.Trim();
```

Here's a sample of my data:

```
  96086 IT085   PATEL RUCHIKKUMAR MAHENDRABHAI&#160;    IT  6   2009-13
```

Answer (score 0):

`&#160;` or `&nbsp;` is the html code for [non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Use this to get rid of it.

```
name = grvExcelData.Rows[g1.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.Replace(@"&#160;", "");
```